# Warning: filemtime(): stat failed for wp_

Tags: php, functions, wp-enqueue-script

Currently getting this warning in php.

```
Warning: filemtime(): stat failed for https://madeupurl.com/wp-content/themes/madeup/assets/js/scripts.js in /var/www/wp-content/themes/madeup/functions.php on line 200
 
This is line 200 on functions.php
wp_enqueue_script('madeup-global', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/scripts.js', array('jquery'), filemtime(get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/scripts.js'), TRUE);
```

Comment: is this your theme? Are you asking how to fix this? Or are you asking why it happens? Your question doesn't contain a question

Comment: Good point. So this is a custom theme that was developed by vendors with who we no longer have contact. The question is both, how do we fix this and why does it happen? Or is it a warning that we can live with?

Comment: You don't need the [`filemtime()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.filemtime.php) call there at all.